# How to edit Calendar title

Tags: 7, datetime

Module: https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar

[image]

I wan to remove Saturday. Only display August 1, 2015.

Picture below show that I already change some setting, but not working at all.

[image]

What should I do? Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The format of the pager header can be modified on the date view configuration page `admin/config/regional/date-time/date-views`. On that page, find the format that you wish to update, in your case **Date views day format with year**, which by default is `l, F j, Y`.

Update that value to be `F j, Y`, since `l` returns the weekday, and your date will show as you need it.

Comment: Thank for your reply. I had changed the setting. Unfortunately, it does not change anything.

Comment: @peifa did you clear the site cache, as well as your browser cache

Comment: @Geoff, I clear the cache as well, but nothing is changed. Please help.