# Remove calendar hyperlink

Tags: 7, datetime

[image]

Can see black circle at the picture below?

How to remove that hyperlink?

Comment: You can do this by using css i.e. `text-decoration: none;`

Comment: @NishantP text-decoration wont help to remove hyperlink

Comment: Refer to link : https://www.drupal.org/node/462748#comment-1631978

Comment: @NishantP Thank you for your reply. Do you know how to solve this? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/156727/how-to-edit-calendar-title

Comment: @NishantP CSS can *hide* hyperlink. It cannot *remove* it, so it's still visible for robots etc.

Comment: Ya I know @Mołot. But they ask about removing hyperlink so I had provide him to solve this issue in easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Due to i only want to post month calendar only. To solve this, just disable day, week and year in the view.